# Vue не работает фильтр uppercase

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

```
<div id="app">
  {{ message | uppercase }}
</div>
```

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: "uppercase"
  }
});
```

[ссылка на пример](https://codepen.io/kakabylik/pen/WKjaqm?editors=1010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто используйте вызов напрямую

```
{{ message.toUpperCase() }}
```

Если это всё, что действительно вам нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Во `Vue` нет встроенных фильтров, создайте свой:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'uppercase'
    },
    filters: {
        uppercase: (value) => value.toUppercase()
    }
});
```

Либо используйте эту же функцию в шаблоне:

```
<div id="app">{{ message.toUppercase() }}</div>
```